# After press the "power button", the computer turn the fans and not boot up

Tags: boot

My computer is not booting up all the time. Sometimes it will, but then freezes, but most of the time it will just turn the fans on and not boot up. I discover that if I press the reboot button, the computer turn off by itself, turn on and then boot up as always.

What could be the problem?

Comment: 2 possibilities, the PSU is bad or a piece of hardware that is powered by it is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Anything hardware related!

Can't provide you an answer but can give you a methodology.

I would recommend removing all components bar the processor and heat sink/fan (for now) and seeing if it boots first time.

Make sure you do cold boot ie turn power off at the wall in between.

Add back one component at a time till you narrow down on the hardware causing problems.

Done this myself a few times. Once it was GPU. Another time it was RAM.